# AS3 Superclass variables and Subclasses error

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, subclass, superclass

I am creating two classes which define the general structure of objects, and many subclasses which are variations of the parents. The variables have the type declaration in the superclasses, and the value declaration in the subclasses. However:

[Body_Part_Armor.as]

```
package  {
    import flash.display.*;
    public class Body_Part_Armor extends MovieClip
    {
        var agility_malus;
        var hp_total;
        var defense;
        var armor_extra_height;
        var armor_extra_width;  
        var hp_left;
        public function Body_Part_Armor()
        {
            hp_left = hp_total;
        }
    }
}
```

[Chest_Armor_1.as]

```
package
{
    public class Chest_Armor_1 extends Body_Part_Armor
    {
        agility_malus = 2;
        hp_total = 20;
        defense = 7;
        armor_extra_height = 10;
        armor_extra_width = 6;

        public function Chest_Armor_1()
        {
        }
    }   
}
```

For the compiler-debug-test Body_Part_Armor and Chest_Armor_1 are completely fine, while

[Weapon.as]

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    public class Weapon extends MovieClip {
        var weapon_type:Number;
        var n_attacks:Number;
        var damage:Number;
        var precision:Number;
        // some other variables in here
        var is_empty_weapon:Boolean;
        public function Weapon()
        {   
        }           
    }
}
```

[Empty_Arm_Weapon.as]

```
package
{
    public class Empty_Arm_Weapon extends Weapon
    {
        is_empty_weapon = true;
        public function Empty_Arm_Weapon() {
        }
    }   
}
```

give me the following error: 
1120: access of undefined property is_empty_weapon
(yet if I write var is_empty_weapon = true; in Empty_Arm_Weapon it will complain about conflict with inherited definition of the variable in the namespace public).

If I define the variable value is_empty_weapon = true in the constructor Empty_Arm_Weapon(), however, i won't get any error.

I guess I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't tell the difference between the two cases, yet one works and the other doesn't. 
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move the assignment of the variable into the constructor like:

```
package
{
    public class Empty_Arm_Weapon extends Weapon
    {
        public function Empty_Arm_Weapon()
        {
            is_empty_weapon = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Alternatively you could declare it with a default value of true if you want this for all inheriting classes

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    public class Weapon extends MovieClip {
        protected var weapon_type:Number;
        protected var n_attacks:Number;
        protected var damage:Number;
        protected var precision:Number;
        // some other variables in here
        protected var is_empty_weapon:Boolean=true;
        public function Weapon()
        {   
        }           
    }
}
```

Also be sure to scope your variables so they can be accessed by sub-classes if that's what you want, mark them protected (accessible by this and sub-classes) or public (accessible to this, sub-classes and instances using this object).

**EDIT**

I believe your specific issue you see in the discrepancy between the behavior may have to do with the fact that you have a typed variable in the second case and in the first case the types are not declared.  This means they would default to undefined instead of false or null or 0 which may create some strange behavior, either way this isn't from all I've learned the right way to go, setup defaults at definition or in sub-classes override defaults in the constructor.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html

Comment: As I already said in the OP, I can get it working with defining the value in the constructor. The question is why then it works fine in  Body_Part_Armor - Chest_Armor_1 with the value declaration in the subclass class definition (not inside the constructor)?

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to do it this way. Anything not in the constructor or in a method should just be a new variable declaration for the class.  Doing assignments here doesn't mean anything to me, when do you expect that assignment to occur?  Before the object is created? then it wouldn't have memory to store those properties.  Only in the constructor or later makes sense to me.  I don't know why that doesn't cause problems for you as is though.

Comment: Was I correct in the way I split up your code being all in separate files?

Comment: I edited my answer to give a more direct suggestion to your main question.

Comment: Yes the code I showed consists of 4 different files. I guess declaring the value in the class doesn't make much sense, it was just the fact that they act as sort of 'constants until something weird modifies them' that drove my crazy mind to do that there. I'm still curious if somebody can come up for an explanation for the inconsistency in the compiler, or what unknown difference they have.  :) Thanks for the help though!

Comment: public class Body_Part_Armor extends MovieClip{
var agility_malus:Number;
I have tried this, but it still won't give me any error :)

Comment: No problem, there's definitely some leniency in AS3 that sometimes makes me crazy too, let me know if you figure it out.  If you have some time and want to get all hard-core about it you could probably grab the SDK and debug the source of the compiler http://incubator.apache.org/flex/download.html I can't seem to find asc by itself in there but there is an AS3Compiler.java that looks pretty promising.

Comment: Ok, the difference was in the main class:
it seems like the AS3 compiler notices the error only once you istantiate that very class. In the main I had created an Empty_Arm_Weapon istance, while I still hadn't create any Chest_Armor_1 
:)

Comment: Ah okay right, so the compiler just starts with your main class and any classes it finds referenced it compiles in or copies from a swc you depend on, so that makes sense again, thanks for responding, you can post as an answer and accept your own eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Also a related issue, if you are loading instances of the super class from within an instance of a subclass, overridden protected functions will throw the "is not a function" error even though in the compiler it shows auto complete for this same function.

The reason is that while the inheritance of classes allows for access to this function, the child object is not at runtime an extension of the parent object but rather a child object that is only by coincidence the super class of the creator.

To remedy this simply mark the function in question as "public function" and user "override public" rather than "override protected" to access it from the parent (subclass), as you normally would.  If the class member MUST be private or protected you'll need to access it another way.